# Flask-wtf form validation unexpectedly activated

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

[image]

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.

I have a form that looks like:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="registerForm"  method="POST" action="/register/" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email address">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit!</button>
        </form>
```

and a 'user' model that looks like:

```
class User(UserMixin, SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True)
    email = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    #: The hashed password
    password = Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    first_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    active = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    is_admin = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, username, email=email, **kwargs)
        if password:
            self.set_password(password)
        else:
            self.password = None
```

My plan is to ask for an email only, verify it and then have the user fill out the rest of the fields later afterwards when they are verified and logged in. So I'd like the entire object created but only the email field filled, at first. When I tested the email signup form (html above) by submitting only the email, I get the screenshot. I know that cookie cutter uses forms built with flask-wtf, but I'm not sure why I am activating this form validation. Why is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the source code you can know that: [user.py](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/forms/user.py#L9)

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = TextField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    first_name = TextField('first_name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    last_name = TextField('last_name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = TextField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    confirm = PasswordField('Verify password', [DataRequired(), EqualTo('password', message='Passwords must match')])
```

you can see that there are six fields and all of them are **required**(via the `DataRequired` validator), and that's the reason why you see the six error message.

Note that `cookiecutter-flask` only give you the basic structure, you need modify some files yourself.